# wsdl2java output produces only the package name

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, wsdl2java, jax-ws-customization

i have used a  sample wsdl in my java code. when i try to print the output it returns only the package name like:

```
com.holidaywebservice.holidayservice_v2.CountryCode@6b6478
```

This happens only when the output was a list.

Part of my code:

```
HolidayService2 hs1= new HolidayService2();

HolidayService2Soap hss1=  hs1.getHolidayService2Soap();

ArrayOfCountryCode acc = hss1.getCountriesAvailable();

system.out.println(acc.getCountryCode());
```

wsdl url:http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 0):

With this `com.holidaywebservice.holidayservice_v2.CountryCode@6b6478` you're trying to print the `ArrayOfCountryCode` object.  Your code instead should be:

```
package com.holidaywebservice.holidayservice_v2.clientsample;

import com.holidaywebservice.holidayservice_v2.*;

public class ClientSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Create Web Service Client..."
            HolidayService2 service1 = new HolidayService2();
            //Create Web Service...
            HolidayService2HttpGet port1 = service1.getHolidayService2HttpGet();

            //call WS
            ArrayOfCountryCode acc =  port1.getCountriesAvailable();
            for(CountryCode cc : acc.getCountryCode()){
                System.out.println("Country code is: " + cc.getCode());
                System.out.println("Country code Description is: " + cc.getDescription());
            }
    }
}
```

**Update** Try just adding the below

```
for(CountryCode cc : acc.getCountryCode()){
    System.out.println("Country code is: " + cc.getCode());
    System.out.println("Country code Description is: " + cc.getDescription());
}
```

After the line `ArrayOfCountryCode acc = hss1.getCountriesAvailable();` in your current code. But you see the gist of it, `acc` is an array of country codes.

Comment: method HolidayService2HttpGet() is undefined in the HolidayService2. can't find the java class (HolidayService2HttpGet.java)